# How can i seect query for product list after order (TRIGGER)

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

My tables:

```
                      Orders                                               Products
Id(PK) |Quantity | Date | ProdIdFK |OrdFK(ref CustomerID)       ProdID(PK) | Quantity  | Name
```

and customer table.
I have to make an order using trigger so i do:

```
INSERT into Orders(Id, Quantity, Date, ProdIDFK, OrdFK) 
    values(3, 2, '2020/01/27', 15, 2);

CREATE TRIGGER  QuantityUpdate
AFTER INSERT
   ON Orders FOR EACH ROW
   
BEGIN
UPDATE Products
SET products.Quantity = Products.Quantity - New.Quantity 
WHERE products.ProdID = New.ProdID

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But just nothing happening, it shows the old quantity and doesnt change. I tried to put INSERT after BEGIN(i dunno what is correct one) and also nothing. What is correct query for this?

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger code looks OK - apart, maybe, for a glitch in the column name spotted by Gordon Linoff.

However, if you want it to fire on the `INSERT` statement that is showed in your script, you need to create it first, then `INSERT`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER QuantityUpdate 
AFTER INSERT ON Orders FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   ...
END$$
DELIMITER ;

INSERT into Orders(Id, Quantity, Date, ProdIDFK, OrdFK) 
VALUES(3, 2, '2020-01-27', 15, 2);
```

Once the trigger is created, it fires for every order inserted. It has no way, however, to take in account inserts that happened before its creation.

Comment: I tried that but it didnt help. I think it must be a problem in trigger.

Comment: [link](https://imghub.io/i/awZPy) What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, the syntax is wrong in either the `INSERT` or the trigger, because one is using `ProdIdfk` and the other `ProdId`.

If the first is the correct name, then the trigger should be:

```
UPDATE Products p
    SET p.Quantity = p.Quantity - New.Quantity 
    WHERE p.ProdID = New.ProdIDFK;
```

Comment: I corrected that but nothing happen, all values still remain. Here links to screens of tables Orders and Products, maybe some proplems are here? [link](https://imghub.io/i/aworU) [link](https://imghub.io/i/awvwa) And here is corrected TRIGGER: [link](https://imghub.io/i/awZPy)